# trying to save new value in to Sqlite Database but DataGridview is not reading NEW user entered data in WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

DataGridVeiw is reading the old data that i display from Database instead of new user entered data.I tried  Mode=TwoWay but still same thing.[ reading each row and entering into Database] Any help?

Here is my XAML code:

```
    <DataGridTextColumn     x:Name="DG_Vname"       Header=" Vendor Name "  MinWidth="50" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=VP_Vname}"       FontFamily="Calibri" IsReadOnly="True" />
                        <!--<DataGridTextColumn     x:Name="DG_VItemNo"     Header=" Vendor SKU# "  MinWidth="50" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=VP_VendorSKU}"   FontFamily="Calibri" Foreground="Blue"/>  -->
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" Vendor SKU# " Width="125">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="DG_VItemNo" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=VP_VendorSKU}" FontFamily="Calibri" TextAlignment="Right" Foreground="Blue" MinWidth="124" Padding="1,0,5,0" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <!--  ================= --> 
                        <!-- <DataGridTextColumn     x:Name="DG_VCaseCost"   Header=" Case Cost "    MinWidth="50" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=VP_SKUcaseCost}" FontFamily="Calibri"/> -->
                        <!--  =================       -->
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" Case Cost " Width="100">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="DG_VCaseCost" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=VP_SKUcaseCost, Mode=TwoWay}" FontFamily="Calibri" TextAlignment="Right" Foreground="Blue" MinWidth="100" Padding="1,0,5,0" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <!--  =================       -->
                        <!-- <DataGridTextColumn     x:Name="DG_VQtyPerCase" Header=" Qty/Case "     MinWidth="50" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=VP_QtyInCase}"   FontFamily="Calibri" /> -->
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" Qty/Case " Width="100">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox x:Name="DG_VQtyPerCase" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=VP_QtyInCase, Mode=TwoWay}" FontFamily="Calibri" Foreground="Blue" MinWidth="100" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <!--  =================       -->
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Preferred" Width="90">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <RadioButton x:Name="DG_isPreferred" HorizontalAlignment="Center" GroupName="Preferred" IsChecked="{Binding Path=VP_isVendorActive, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxWidth="25" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <!--  =================       -->

                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

and here is my XAML.CS :

```
    private void SaveVendorList()
    {
        int NOR = DG_VendorPur.Items.Count;
        DG_VendorPur.SelectedIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < NOR; i++)
        {

            DG_VendorPur.SelectedItem = DG_VendorPur.Items[i];
            DataRowView DRow    = (DataRowView)DG_VendorPur.SelectedItems[0];
            string R_No         = DRow["VP_SrNo"].ToString();
            string R_ProdID     = TB_PscanID.Text;
            string R_isPref     = DRow["VP_isVendorActive"].ToString();
            string R_Name       = DRow["VP_Vname"].ToString();
            string R_SKU        = DRow["VP_VendorSKU"].ToString();
            string R_CaseCost   = DRow["VP_SKUcaseCost"].ToString();
            string R_CaseQty    = DRow["VP_QtyinCase"].ToString();

            MessageBox.Show(R_No+" : "+ R_ProdID+ " : " +R_isPref+" : "+ R_Name + " : " + R_SKU + " : " + R_CaseCost + " : " + R_CaseQty);

            using (SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString))
            using (var cmd = sqliteCon.CreateCommand())
                try
                {
                    sqliteCon.Open();
                    int SrNo = VPrecord + 1;
                    if ((Save_UpdateVendorList == "Save")&&(int.Parse(R_No) == NOR ))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "insert into VendorProducts (VP_SrNo,VP_ProductID,VP_isVendorActive,VP_Vname,VP_VendorSKU,VP_SKUcaseCost,VP_QtyinCase )values(@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4,@val5,@val6,@val7)";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "update VendorProducts set VP_SrNo=@val1 ,VP_ProductID=@val2 ,VP_isVendorActive=@val3 ,VP_Vname=@val4 ,VP_VendorSKU=@val5 ,VP_SKUcaseCost=@val6 ,VP_QtyinCase=@val7 where VP_SrNo =@val1 ";
                    }
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", R_No);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", R_ProdID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", R_isPref);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", R_Name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val5", R_SKU);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val6", R_CaseCost);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val7", R_CaseQty);

                    cmd.Prepare();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqliteCon.Close();
                    Save_Update = "";
                    DispDataGrid();
                    CB_VendorSearch.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show how did you bind DataGrid to the datasource.

Comment: Solved. i need to add UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in to my databinging. Like ... Text="{Binding Path=VP_VendorSKU, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged ,Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: @Vadim Martynov : Thanks a Lot !!!